# Contract function works on Remix but not works on web3js

Tags: web3js, remix

I've a contract, more complex than the following but the concept is the same

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract SimpleCatalog{
    bytes32[] internal x;

    constructor () public{
      x.push(0xa);
      x.push(0xb);
      x.push(0xc);
    }

    function getX() external view returns (bytes32[]){
      return x;
    }
}
```

When I execute the function in Remix, it returns all the values that I expect that are:

```
0: bytes32[]: 
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a,
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b,
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c
```

But if I invoke it with Web3JS, that is:

```
const web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
console.log(web3.version) //0.19.0
const catalog = 
  (web3.eth.contract(props.catalog.abi)).at(props.catalog.address);
catalog.getX(res => {console.log(res)})
```

the console prints `null`. I really don't see the point! Why the function works on Remix and not on Web3JS?

Answer (score 1):

The callback parameters are: (error, result). In order to see the expected values from Web3, last line have to be changed i

`catalog.getX((err,res) => {console.log(res)})`